# Unable to use barteksc PDF Viewer in my app

Tags: android

I tried to use [bartecksc AndroidPdfViewer][1]

[1]: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer in my android app to view PDF files from the assets folder inside the app but it is not working. It shows a blank screen.
Here is what I did:
I added this dependency in the build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.1.0-beta.1'
```

(I even tried using `implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'`)

I added the following widget in activity_main.xml

```
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

I put the following code in the onCreate method

```
PDFView pdfView=findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromAsset("sample_file.pdf");
```

The file that I wanted to display was located in the assets folder with the name sample_file.pdf

Following is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.umersoftwares.bartekscpdfview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PDFView pdfView=findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromAsset("sample_file.pdf");
    }
}
```

Following is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My build.gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.umersoftwares.bartekscpdfview"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that it was necessary to call the `.load()` method on the PDFView object to display the pdf. So, in the java file, it should be like this

```
pdfView.fromAsset("sample_file.pdf")
.load();
```

Instead of only:

```
pdfView.fromAsset("sample_file.pdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is missing necessary permissions for reading storage.

there is a demo over github with the library that you posted. check the code for requesting read storage permission and implement it in your code.

You can refer this sample class of demo provided with library.

https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/barteksc/sample/PDFViewActivity.java